# how can import "export user object" in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

*Step 1:*

I went to the tools menu in origin oracle pl sql then choose export user object and select that file i need to convert to destination database like view and functions and packages etc...

*Step 2 :*

after that i went to destination database and open new command window and paste that file create in **step1**.
after that i get this error for many objects:

`ora00900 : invalid sql statement`

how can i import that file created with pl/sql export user object?

Comment: you did a cut&paste or you transfered the file and ran it? check if you have any redundant CRLF (e.g. copying from Windows to a linux may bring that).

Comment: "choose export user object"...ok, but what kind of export did you do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle SQL Developer and trying to export DDL and Data, make sure that selected format is "insert". Other formats are not applicable to run as SQL statement.
If your goal is full export consider using Oracle DataPump: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html